# Which of the following way is good way to initialize

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I am a new Objective-C programmer and sometimes confused with those ownership concepts of this language....currently i am learning the iPhone  programming....

Here are case those confused me always..

i use normally these (sometimes first and sometimes other)

```
 NSMutableArray *array;     //Declared in header
```

**case 1**

```
array1= [databaseClass getData];
```

**Case 2**

```
array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[databaseClass getData]];
```

Here `[databaseClass getData]` returns a nonAutoreleased array of objects..
I just want to conforms that is anyone of them is correct ?

and if not then please suggest the correct one....

**EDIT**

I mean to say that `[databaseClass getData]` already returning me an allocated array (i means a non-autoreleased array) now i think i do not need to allocate  my array if i want to use it in my class (i have tested this and it works) , here my only question is about that `array1` initialization....Does anyone of those above statements make any sense......if no then i request that please provide a block of code so that it becomes more clear to me.....
Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Both* cases should give you an autoreleased object. You're the owner if:

- You allocated the object via `alloc`.
- You created a copy of an object via a method that contains the word `copy`, as in `mutableCopy` (the returned copy belongs to you, not the object on which you called the `copy` method).
- You `retain`ed it.

In all other cases you can assume that you are not the owner and that you do not need to release the object.

So if your `getData` method does not return an autoreleased object you should modify it so it does. Otherwise other people using this code will create memory leaks (and you're likely to confuse yourself this way).

**Edit** after question got edited:

According to the naming convention in Objective-C, the `getData` method should return an autoreleased object. So it should be edited to return an autoreleased object if it doesn't already.

If you want to edit the array you do need to make a mutable copy from it. You can either call `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[databaseClass getData]];` or `[[databaseClass getData] mutableCopy]`. In the first case, the array is autoreleased, you are *not* the owner and you do *not* need to call `release` on it. In the second case, you *are* the owner (as per the `copy` rule) and need to release it later on.

Comment: Probably the second one means a extra method call, expensive :-P

Comment: ok....please also clear me that here i am using [databaseClass getData] that returns me an allocated array.....then my thinking is that i should not allocate my array again...and must release it because it is now pointer to that array of database class

Comment: @Praveen S: I don't understand what you mean. I just listed the Objective-C ownership rules, that has nothing to do with "extra method calls".

Comment: @RSS: Sorry, I don't understand this question. Can you explain in more detail ?

Comment: @DarkDust: Yeah you are right, i got to learn something from it. I wanted to point out that the second one means there is extra method call to create a array. Memory wise both are same.

Comment: @DarkDust -- I have Edited my Question please use that to help me